# Recursive call not returning true to main algo function (Python)

Tags: python

Having a bit of difficulty with a recursive function call here.  This is a Hamiltonian path algo and I am trying to debug my code but have reached a dead end.  I have posted my code below where my hamMain checks each vertex and my hamWalk walks through the vertexes not already in the path.

All this code works great so far.  I will post some debugging code below as well.

Once the program finds a match (where the path length taken is equal to the number of vertices) it should output true to my main yet all it does is go to the next starting vertex in hamMain.  I assume this has something to do with the recursive nature of my program and thought someone with more experience could push me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
class HamProgram:
    def get_graph(self):
        adj_lines = []
        test = "input001.txt"
        with open(test, 'r') as adjFile:
        # with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as adjFile:
            adjFile.readline()
            for line in adjFile:
                adj_lines.append(line.strip())
        G = nx.parse_adjlist(adj_lines, nodetype=int)
        return G

    def ham_walk(self, graph, path):
        k = len(path)
        print("current length of path")
        print(len(path))
        n = len(graph.nodes())
        print("Path")
        print(path)
        print("Neighbors")
        print(nx.neighbors(graph, path[-1]))
        if k == n:
            print("Here")
            return True
        for neighbor in nx.neighbors(graph, path[-1]):
            if neighbor not in path:
                print("Current neighbor")
                print(neighbor)
                path.append(neighbor)
                self.ham_walk(graph, path)
        return False

    def ham_main(self):
        graph = self.get_graph()
        print(graph.nodes())
        print(graph.edges())
        for node in graph.nodes():
            path = [node]
            if self.ham_walk(graph, path): #THIS DOESN'T PASS could it be with the self.ham_walk call?
                print("found path")
                output = "Hamiltonian Path: " + path
                break
            else:
                output = "False"
        return output

 class Main:
     execute = HamProgram()
     print(execute.ham_main())
```

Here is some debugging proof that it finds the path

```
   Current neighbor
   8
   current length of path
   9
   Path
   [0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 8]

  [0]
  [0, 3]
  [0, 3, 6]
  [0, 3, 6, 7]
  [0, 3, 6, 7, 4]
  [0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1]
  [0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2]
  [0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5]
  [0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 8]
```

Here is where it should return true and print the path but it doesn't, what gives?

EDIT: I have marked where I believe the issue is.

Thanks

Comment: ```self.ham_walk(graph, path)``` - you don't return anything when you recurse.

Comment: Why do these classes even exist? This isn't Java; you don't need to stick absolutely everything in a class.

Comment: [Reason for return statement in recursive function call](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/201765)